# compare two comma separated strings and list the common values

Tags: linux, bash

How many I compare the two comma separated list (master and input) and list the common values among them (result) while preserving the order of elements in master list. For example:

case1:

```
master="common,city,country"
input="city,country"

result="city,country"
```

case 2:

```
master="common,city,country"
input="country,pig,cat,common"

result="common,country"
```

case 3:

```
master="common,city,country"
input="pigs,cars,train"

result="nothing found"
```

This is what I tried:

```
result="$(awk -F, -v master_list=$master'{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if (master_list~ $i) { echo $i } } } END ' <<< $input)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one awk-oneliner solution:

```
awk -v RS=",|\n" 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}
    {a[$0]++}a[$0]>1{r=r?r","$0:$0}
    END{print r?r:"Nothing found"}' <(<<< $master) <(<<<$input)
```

Test with your 3 cases:

Case 1

```
kent$ master="common,city,country"
kent$ input="city,country"
kent$ result=$(awk -v RS=",|\n" 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}{a[$0]++}a[$0]>1{r=r?r","$0:$0}END{print r?r:"Nothing found"}' <(<<< $master) <(<<<$input))
kent$ echo $result
city,country
```

Case 2

```
kent$ master="common,city,country"
kent$ input="country,pigs,cat,common"
kent$ result=$(awk -v RS=",|\n" 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}{a[$0]++}a[$0]>1{r=r?r","$0:$0}END{print r?r:"Nothing found"}' <(<<< $master) <(<<<$input))
kent$ echo $result
country,common
```

Case 3

```
kent$ master="common,city,country"
kent$ input="pigs,cars,train"
kent$ result=$(awk -v RS=",|\n" 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}{a[$0]++}a[$0]>1{r=r?r","$0:$0}END{print r?r:"Nothing found"}' <(<<< $master) <(<<<$input))
kent$ echo $result
Nothing found
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to change your script when master is already defined as variable while input is coming from user. However, it seems that I am doing some mistake:


result="$(awk -F, -v a=$master '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if (a ~ $i) { print $i  }  } } ' <<< $input)"

Comment: you were not changing my codes, you were rewriting my codes. You are using a different approach to solve the problem. Dont know why you put the comment under my answer.  It makes no difference if the `master` was given by user or not. I used the `master` as **already defined** shell variable too, so does `$input` @Jaanna

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` with `BASH` string manipulations:

```
cmn() {
   local master="$1"
   local input="$2"
   result=$(grep -Ff <(printf "%s\n" ${input//,/ }) <(printf "%s\n" ${master//,/ }))
   echo "${result//$'\n'/,}"
}


cmn "common,city,country" "city,country"
city,country

cmn "common,city,country" "country,pig,cat,common"
common,country

cmn "common,city,country" "pigs,cars,train"
```

Comment: I like most of it. Can you use `result=$(grep -Ff <(printf "%s\n" ${input//,/ }) <(printf "%s\n" ${master//,/ }))` avoiding `echo -n` ?

Comment: Thanks @WalterA for good suggestion. It is edited in answer now.

Comment: How would you do the reverse solution? I'd like to get the strings in A or B but not in both.

Comment: I would use `awk` for that instead of `grep`

Answer (score 1):

You can use comm utility

```
my_comm() { 
  res=$(comm -12 <(echo "$1" | tr ',' '\n' | sort) <(echo "$2" | tr ',' '\n' | sort) | xargs | tr ' ' ',')
  [[ -z $res ]] && echo nothing found || echo $res 
}
```

out

```
> my_comm common,city,country city,country
city,country
> my_comm common,city,country country,pig,cat,common
common,country
> my_comm common,city,country pigs,cars,train
nothing found
```